# Error while Inserting Image to the Excel using Apache POI 3.6

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi there I am using POI 3.6

I want to insert image into the Excel, but when I create image I am getting error like this

```
java.io.EOFException
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:330)   at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:330)

at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:565)    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:565)

at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readUTF(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:309) at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readUTF(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:309)

at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.parse_iTXt_chunk(PNGImageReader.java:443) at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.parse_iTXt_chunk(PNGImageReader.java:443)

at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:647) at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:647)

at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1309)   at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1309)

at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1579)    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1579)

at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:923) at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:923)

at org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension(ImageUtils.java:66)  at org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension(ImageUtils.java:66)

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getImageDimension(XSSFPicture.java:284)    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getImageDimension(XSSFPicture.java:284)

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(XSSFPicture.java:200) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(XSSFPicture.java:200)

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:167)   at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:167)

at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:154)   at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.resize(XSSFPicture.java:154)

at com.yagnaiq.core.ui.renderer.grid.ExportExcelHelper.insertChartToExcel(ExportExcelHelper.java:137)
```

My code is like this.

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/dev/workspaces/4.2.3/YagnaWebJSP/WebRoot/images/Forum_Sprite.png");

        byte[] picData = null;
        File pic = new File( "C:\\dev\\workspaces\\4.2.3\\YagnaWebJSP\\WebRoot\\images\\Forum_Sprite.png" );
        long length = pic.length();
        picData = new byte[ ( int ) length ];
        FileInputStream picIn = new FileInputStream( pic );
        picIn.read( picData );
        int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture( picData, HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG );

        /*if (imageByteArray == null)
            imageByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(imageByteArray, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                    */
        inputStream.close();

        // Returns an object that handles instantiating concrete classes
        CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        // Creates the top-level drawing patriarch.
        Drawing drawing = chartSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        // Create an anchor that is attached to the worksheet
        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        // set top-left corner for the image
        anchor.setCol1(3);
        anchor.setRow1(2);

        // Creates a picture
        Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
        // Reset the image to the original size
        pict.resize();
```

Please suggest what is missing here.

Also I am getting "pictureIdx" always Zero (0) , weather this is Correct or no ?

Comment: Have you tried with a more recent version of Apache POI? eg the latest one?

Comment: yes, I have tried.. but there were few other issues.. so not compactible.. so we need to use this POI only..